# Declare Var in If Statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, variables

yes i know there is a bunch of other threads with likely the same question... but i still dont get it.

I'm writing in C# via Visual Studio and want to make something like an menu so you can choose different options... dependind on which option you choose, the variable will change.

But it's important to have only one variable, so the variable will change when the user is chooses an option.

Something like this:

```cs
stt:
string m = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Clear();
int c = Convert.ToInt32(m);
if (c == 1)
{
  var ttt = "one";
}
if (c == 2)
{
  var ttt = "two";
}
else {
  goto stt;
}
Console.WriteLine("" + ttt);
Console.ReadKey();
```

I always get the error

> The name 'ttt' does not exist in the current context

So I have to declare the var outside the if statement... but how??

Comment: Please look into variable scopes and code blocks, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/csharp-code-blocks/) may help you.

Comment: I highly recommend that you not use `goto` and instead try to write code using loops and if statements instead.

Comment: @juharr on other hand code looks generated with some sort of tool using random variable names - in that case goto may be fine... Cross-compiling some custom language into very stripped-down version of C# would be my choice before going to some lower level target... (not 100% serious comments)

Comment: Also that should be `else if(c == 2)` otherwise when `c` is 1 it will still go into the `else` with the `goto`

Answer (score -1):

By writing..

```
string ttt;
```

..above the first if. You can't write `var ttt;` above the if, because it doesn't declare the type (and you're not providing a value so the compiler cannot infer the type), so you have to give the type (string) when you declare the name

If you do this you'll have to remove the `var`s inside the ifs (but leave eg `ttt = "one"`) so you don't end up declaring another variable with the same name

Comment: im coding with with Leaf.xNet so it has to be "Var", i cant use string :(

Comment: That being the case, you'll have to write `var ttt = ""` above the first if, then. Next time, if there are constraints such as "must not use the word string" you should mention them in the question, not in comments to answers. Also, you use string yourself then you say `string m = Console.ReadLine()` so I'm not really sure what your "can't use `string` rule even means.. "

Answer (score -1):

The quick of it is:

```
stt:
string m = Console.ReadLine();
string ttt;
Console.Clear();
int c = Convert.ToInt32(m);
if (c == 1)
{
ttt = "one";
}
if (c == 2)
{
ttt = "two";
}
else 
{
goto stt;
}
Console.WriteLine("" + ttt);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Why? Concept called variable scopes. In your sample, `ttt` was only created inside the `if` statement, or the `else` statement, and therefore would not live beyond the scope of that statement. In order to address `ttt` outside of those limited scopes, it had to be declared higher up.

Off topic - `goto`. Please try to use loops or conditionals.

Comment: im coding with with Leaf.xNet so it has to be "Var", i cant use string :( ... but i will look up for loops!

Comment: @Crussy You could do `var ttt = c == 1 ? "one" : c == 2 ? "two" : null;` then `if(ttt == null) goto stt;`  But I have no idea what Leaf.xNet is or why it wouldn't let you use `string` and if it restricts that then my suggestion might not work either.